# How to unit test Redux thunk dispatches in Promise.all

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say I have two Redux thunk functions like so:

```
const fetchUser = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetch('/my-user-endpoint').then(res => {
            dispatch(updateUserInfo(res))
        }) 
    }
}

const fetchSomethingElse = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetch('/my-other-endpoint').then(res => {
            dispatch(updateOtherInfo(res))
        }) 
    }
}
```

And then an exposed function that uses `Promise.all` to bundle the fetch calls together.

```
export const doSomething = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(firstDoThis())
        dispatch(thenDoThis())

        const fetches = [dispatch(fetchUserInfo()), dispatch(fetchSomethingElse())]

        return Promise.all(fetches).then(() => {
            dispatch(finallyDoThis())
        })
    }
}
```

When trying to test this, I do something like:

```
it('Test', async () => {
    await doSomething()(dispatchMock)
    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(5)
})
```

Instead, I get only 3 dispatches instead of 5. How would I test that Redux thunk dispatches in `Promise.all` is executed?

Comment: I wouldn't test how many times `dispatch` has been called, that's an implementation detail of your thunk. The usual approach is that you assert that some plain actions (like `firstDoThis`) are dispatched in a certain order and that it finally leaves the state in a certain shape. You don't need to test that `Promise.all` actually works, that's just assumed. To answer this differently, you test that the dispatches inside `Promise.all` work by asserting that after `finallyDoThis` has been dispatched, the state is in the expected shape.

Comment: I made a minimal demo, the mocked dispatch has been called 5 times. Close the question since the issue can not be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

In your third function -

1. `doSomething = dispatch => ... <returnValue>`, is called as `doSomething()(dispatchMock)`
2. which binds `dispatch` to `undefined` and calls `returnValue(dispatchMock)`.

So what is `returnValue`?

1. `returnValue` is the result of `doSomething()`
2. which is `Promise.all(fetches)...`

So... type mismatch -

1. `returnValue(dispatchMock)` says "call function `returnValue` with this argument, `dispatchMock`
2. but `returnValue` is a Promise, not a Function.

Maybe you meant -

```js
const doSomething = () => dispatch => ...`
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is exactly what I meant and it was the result of a translation issue when converting the code I had to StackOverflow. I'll edit my question. However, my issue still stands.